# Internet permission doesn't work on API 23

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I encountered strange problem with running on real device(API 23). I tested my app on emulator(API 19) before and it worked just fine. My application using Internet permission for querying API. 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` is stated in my manifest file and as I read Internet permission belongs to `PROTECTION_NORMAL` group in the new permission model. I checked setting on the mobile phone and application has Internet permission. But app acts as permission is absent( I used logs to find the problem and logging stops just on Internet request in my code).

It could be really newbie question but this is my first time when I ran my application on the real device, so excuse me if it is.

Comment: @Rotwang How can it be duplicate if Internet permission isn't dangerous?

Comment: Perhaps you have [the permission in the wrong place](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html). If you are crashing, [use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this). And, overall, you will have better luck on Stack Overflow if you provide a [mcve] illustrating the problem.